# Partitioning hard disk in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have a 640 GB hard drive (that shows up as having 590GB).

I partitioned the drive into two partitions, 300 and 290 GB, the former being `C:` (where Win7 is installed)

I want to partition it so that I have 4 partitions, where the Windows partition gets 150GB and the other get 50, 50, 50, and whatever is remaining.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Right clicking the partition in disk management allows me to shrink the volume and repartition it elsewhere. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) is a link, just in case you need help navigating there.